# margin property not working for text div

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to move the text `.col-6 .about` to the right of the image but nothing is working.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/M4rDD/

**CSS**

```
.mainInfo
{
    height:500px;
    background-color: pink;

}

.col-6 .imagePlaceholder
{
    float: left;
    width:300px;
    height:420px;
    margin:30px 0 30px 30px;    
    background-color: red;
}

.col-6 .about
{
    display: block;
    margin-left:100px;
    padding:1em;
}
```

Comment: Use `margin:30px 30px 30px 30px;` - http://jsfiddle.net/M4rDD/1/ ?

Comment: margin:30px; in .col-6
or use overflow:hidden in .about, like this http://jsfiddle.net/M4rDD/2/

Comment: or like this http://jsfiddle.net/M4rDD/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using css parameters such as :

position:absolute

for the objects you need to move, and then values as left:00px  and right:00px.

Use position:relative for the main wrapper div.

p.s. i rarely use margin value for div, because it's interpreted on different ways across different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

because the floated red div is taken out of the document flow and although the text surrounds the floated red div, the margin is still calculated against the parent `col-6` which has the width of 100% (display:block) of the `mainInfo`). So you have to set the `margin-left` larger than the width of the floated red div (which is `300px`). In this case you may have to set the `margin-left` to `400px`:

```
.col-6 .about {
  display: block;
  margin-left:400px;
  padding:1em;
}
```

I added this answer to show that the `margin-left` still works. You can also set the margin for the floated red div instead (like *JunM* posted as a comment).

Here is the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/M4rDD/4/).